# I m trying to do an oop variant to the life game, but i am having an error, code below

Tags: python

I am getting this error when i m running the program, do you have any idea?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/app.py", line 83, in <module>
    a = Game(x,y,t)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Code :

```
from math import ceil, floor, sqrt
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class Person:
    people = []

    def __init__(self, x, y, alive):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.alive = alive
        Person.people.append(self)
        return

    def kill(self, t):
        self.alive[t] = False
        return

     def resurrect(self, t):
        self.alive[t] = True
        return

    def neighbours(self):
        a = []
        people = Person.people
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x and z.y == self.y + 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x and z.y == self.y - 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x - 1 and z.y == self.y]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x - 1 and z.y == self.y + 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x - 1 and z.y == self.y - 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x + 1 and z.y == self.y - 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x + 1 and z.y == self.y + 1]
        a += [z for z in people if z.x == self.x + 1 and z.y == self.y]
        return a

    def alive_neighbours(self, t):
        a = [z for z in self.neighbours() if z.alive[t]]
        return a


class Game:
    def __init__(self, n, m, t):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.t = t
        return

    def setup(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            for j in range(self.m):
                a = [False] * self.t
                a[0] = random.choice([True, False])
                Person(i, j, a)
        return

    def stage(self, t):
        for person in Person.people:
            if person.alive[t - 1]:
                if len(person.alive_neighbours(t - 1)) < 2:
                    person.kill(t)
                if len(person.alive_neighbours(t - 1)) in [2, 3]:
                    person.resurrect(t)
                if len(person.alive_neighbours(t - 1)) > 3:
                    person.kill(t)
            else:
                if len(person.alive_neighbours(t - 1)) == 3:
                    person.resurrect(t)
        return

    def play(self):
        self.setup()
        for i in range(1, self.t):
            self.stage(i)
        return

    def results(self):
        people = Person.people
        a = [[z.x, z.y, z.alive] for z in people]
        print(a)
        return a

 a = Game(x,y,t)
 a.play()
 a.results()

 for j in range(t):
     b = []
     for i in range(x):
         b.append([z[2][j] for z in a.results() if z[0]==i])
     plt.spy(b)
     plt.savefig(f"time{j}.png")
```

Comment: Is `x` defined?  It looks like it isn't.  When you call `Game(x, y, t)` you are passing as its arguments variables `x`, `y`, and `t` none of which appear to be defined.

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names. What are `self.n`, `self.m`, and `self.t` supposed to mean?

Comment: And you dont need to write ``return`` in every function.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you did not define (assign a value) to x. You need to set x to a certain value before your code executes this line :  a = Game(x,y,t).
This is also true for variable y and t.
So in other words, you are passing undefined values to the Game() constructor. Therefore, define x, y, t first.